# release/close capture of camera

Tags: camera, v4l, opencv

I have opened webcam for capturing using OpenCV in C++.
Then I stopped the program using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>;

The webcam could not turn off, Because was not defined in program. And I can not start my program again because the capture program is still using webcam and is busy.

Error:

```
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
...
```

I found the process id using `lsof|grep libv4l2`:

```
capture   5591     mylove  mem       REG                8,8     52584  1737777 /usr/lib64/libv4l2.so.0.0.0
```

and tried to close the capture using `kill 5591` and also `pkill capture` using normal user and root user. But the camera LED is still turned on and my program can not start.

What is fastest and best method to release/close the camera?

Comment: Could you add the output of `ps -eo uid,state,comm`? The line with your process (`capture`) would be enough.

Comment: Of course, Now I have not OpenCV on my System. I'll put it when I install if I remember. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, the process is sending to background, so never was stopped. 
You can see your processes in background with `jobs` command. And restore the process with `fg` command.

Try to stop the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Then the issue is that, I can not stop the process using Ctrl + C. Because the camera reader, is in infinite loop. and won't stop using this signal.
Maybe it's better to create a function to listen to Ctrl + Z or maybe Ctrl + C signal and then close the camera using it.